# Сохранение value полей формы в Модель

Tags: python, django

def model_form(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormContact(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

else:
    form = FormContact()

return render(request, 'lesson2_contact_create/insert_contacts.html', {'form': form})
```

**моя вьюшка, собственно её и нужно дополнить параметрами на подобии save()**`

class Contact(models.Model):

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

**моделька в которую я хочу сохранить value ввведенных полей, используя форму ниже**

```
class FormContact(forms.Form):

   name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

**Что добавить в view function для реализации сохранения value введенных полей?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен: if form.is_valid():

```
    cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
    name = cleaned_data['name']
    last_name = cleaned_data['last_name']
    email = cleaned_data['email']
    Contact.objects.create(name=name, last_name=last_name, email=email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Дело в том, что я делаю двумя способами, дабы увидить разницу. Наследуя MidelForm и forms.Form